# Outputting the alphabetic characters from a string

Tags: php, regex

Lets say we have a var of the data type string. The value of the string has both alphabetic characters, and a number (an integer) in it. See below for an example.

```
$input = 'foobar777barfoe';
```

I want to write a function which returns only the alphabetic characters from that string. 
The result of the function should be `foobarbarfoe` .

I guess I've to use regular expressions to do this.

I humbly ask for an aid in writing this function.

Comment: `$input = str_replace(range(0, 9), '', $input);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways of doing it. The recommended approach is to use regular expressions.
`"/[^a-zA-Z]/"` matches all the characters that are not in the range a to z and A to Z. ^ in regex means exclude.

```
$input = 'foobar777barfoe';
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $input);
```

`$result` would have a value `"foobarbarfoe"`.

the other primitive way of doing this is to loop through each character and appending the characters that you want. You can use ASCII codes to simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

Interested in non ASCII letters?

Use the Unicode solution:

```
$input = "foobár777fôofoeöäüß";
$result = preg_replace("/\P{L}+/u", "", $input);
```

Output:

> foobárfôofoeöäüß

`\P{L}` is a [Unicode Category](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop), The L is for the Property "Letter" in any language and the uppercase `P` is the negation, means match anything that is not a letter.

Answer (score 1):

```
[^a-zA-Z]
```

Try this.Replace by `emptry string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/40

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = 'foobar777barfoe';
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $input);
//ouput foobarbarfoe
```